# How to recognize that 'Please Select' option is selected

Tags: php, html

Below I have a php/mysqli block of code where it creates a drop down menu:

```
    $moduleHTML  = "";  
    $moduleHTML .= '<select name="modules" id="modulesDrop">'.PHP_EOL;
 $moduleHTML .= '<option value="">Please Select</option>'.PHP_EOL;  

     while($sqlstmt->fetch()) { 
         $moduleHTML .= sprintf('<option value="%1$s_%2$s_%3$s">%1$s - %2$s</option>'.PHP_EOL, $dbModuleNo, $dbModuleName, $dbModuleId);
    } 

$moduleHTML .= '</select>';
```

The HTML for this is:

```
<select name="modules" id="modulesDrop">
     <option value="">Please Select</option>
</select>
```

Now I am trying to display a message if the user has selected the option `Please Select`. But problem is that the message is not being displayed. MY question is how can I get message to be displayed stating that a Module needs to be selected if user selects `Please Select`?

Below is main code:

```
    <?php

    ...


        $moduleHTML  = "";  
        $moduleHTML .= '<select name="modules" id="modulesDrop">'.PHP_EOL;
     $moduleHTML .= '<option value="">Please Select</option>'.PHP_EOL;  

         while($sqlstmt->fetch()) { 
             $moduleHTML .= sprintf('<option value="%1$s_%2$s_%3$s">%1$s - %2$s</option>'.PHP_EOL, $dbModuleNo, $dbModuleName, $dbModuleId);
        } 

    $moduleHTML .= '</select>'; 

        $pHTML = "";

    ?>

    <form action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post">
    <table>
    <tr>
    <th>Module: <?php echo $moduleHTML; ?></th>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <p><input id="moduleSubmit" type="submit" value="Submit Module" name="moduleSubmit" /></p>
    </form>

    <?php


    if (isset($_POST['moduleSubmit'])){ 

    if (isset($_POST['modules']) && $_POST['modules'] == '' ){
    $pHTML = "<span style='color: red'>Please Select a Module</span>";
    }else{


    $assessmentform = "<div id='lt-container'>
    <form action='".htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])."' method='post' id='assessmentForm'>
    <p id='warnings'>{$pHTML}</p>
    <p><strong>View Assessment Details:</p>   
    name='sessionSubmit' /></p>
    </form>
    </div>";

    echo $assessmentform;

    }

    }
?>
```

Comment: This message should be displayed before or after submiting form? Both can be found after 30 secs searching for it with Google.

Comment: @Kamo What I thought is that the first $pHTML string before form just sets that vairable to that message, then I wanted to echo `$pHTML` using {$pHTML} in form

Comment: It's templating system for PHP - it uses tag like your {$pHTML} to render PHP inside HTML :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have given **value = ""** for the option **Please Select**. So you can directly check the element. Also, you have done it. Please check the line,

```
if (isset($_POST['modules']) && $_POST['modules'] == '' ){
    $pHTML = "<span style='color: red'>Please Select a Module</span>";
}else{
```

This line will check whether the user selected any value or not.

Comment: Then put echo for $_POST['modules']  and check does it show any value?

Comment: No echo appears, the output of the else statement is working fine, but the if statement is not displaying an echo

Comment: put echo $_POST['modules'] above if condition and check. I think it must have any value. Thats why it doesn't come inside if condition.

Comment: No echo appears when I choose `Please Select`, If I choose any other option drop down menu which does have a value, it echos those values

Comment: Just now i did this in my system. It works cool. It comes inside if condition when i don't select any value and i put echo $pHTML inside if condition. It displays warning message perfectly. Just check your code whether you have made any mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Use echo statement as marked bold in the below code

```
if (isset($_POST['moduleSubmit'])){ 

if (isset($_POST['modules']) && $_POST['modules'] == '' ){
**echo** $pHTML = "<span style='color: red'>Please Select a Module</span>";
}else{
```

Comment: No echo happens when I included the echo

Comment: Can you add print_r($_POST); in your page and give me the result, so that it would be easy to help you

Comment: user1930247, thats what I told you in the beginning. I also included echo statement as above.